# Why am I not having the expected returned value using recursion?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, return-value

I'm currently working on a project that recreates the printf function in C, however, I'm having trouble implementing my code while I use recursion.
Note that I'm only allowed to use the write function, and one of the functions that I'm working on and having issues is the one that I have to print a pointer.

This is my function for printing the address:

```
int ft_print_address(long unsigned int nb)
{
    int     counter;

    if (nb == 0)
        return(write(1, "(nil)", 5));
    else
    {
        counter = write(1, "0x", 2);
        counter += print_hex(nb);
        return (counter);    
    }
}

static int print_hex(long unsigned int nb)
{
    int         counter;
    char    *hex;

    counter = 0;
    hex = "0123456789abcdef";
    if (nb > 9) 
    {
      print_hex(nb / 16);
    }
    counter += write(1, &hex[nb % 16], 1);
    return (counter);
}
```

the variable (counter) which is the return value of the number of characters written, is always 1, even if number of characters written is superior. The recursion is working because it's printing the address in hexadecimal just like the printf function, but the counter never increases.

Can someone help me?

Comment: `if (nb > 9)` - why 9 here?

Comment: `counter` will always be `1`, because you are only assigning it with value returned by `write` of a single character. You forgot to assign it with return value of the recursive call.

Comment: OT: your code will behave differently than `printf` when there's an error in the `write` call. The  return value from `write` is -1 when an error occurs. And the return value from `printf` should be a negative number in that case. So a line like `counter += write(...);` doesn't handle errors correctly.

Comment: If you're not aware, each call of `print_hex` gets its own variable `counter`. Changing it in the inner execution frame does not change the variable in the outer frame.

Comment: pedrooc16, poor stack overflow etiquette to change the question once answers arrive.  Post rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

I take it that `write(1, c, 1)` will print exactly one character and return 1. It's my best guess.

You are not taking into account the number of characters printed by the recursive call. If `nb` is, say, `0x1234`, then it will have `print_hex(0x1234 / 16)` print 3 characters, and then it will print the `4`.

Your condition for callin `print_hex` recursively is also wrong. A hex number will have more than one digit if it is larger than 15, not 9.

I also take this is homework, so I won't write the code down. But these two changes should be enough.